# How to search defined class or variable's location

Tags: php, undefined, fatal-error

These errors keep coming after changing the PHP website to new server.

1st - Solved by "shaddy"

```
Notice: Undefined variable: es in /home/musthand/public_html/external/site/header.php on line 2

<?php 
if(!is_object($es))
{
    require_once('includes/EliteScript.php');
    $es = new EliteScript();
    $sMemberId = $es->getMemberId();
}

// Get the base URL
$sBaseUrl   = $es->getConfig('baseUrl');
$sImageUrl  = $es->getConfig('imageUrl');
$sMemberId  = $es->getMemberId();
$sUsername  = $es->getMemberUsername($sMemberId);
$sIP        = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// Vars we want to pass to the system
$aJSVars = array(
        'member_url'    => $es->getConfig('memberUrl'),
        'base_url'      => $es->getCOnfig('baseUrl'),
        'image_url'     => $es->getConfig('imageUrl'),
        'date'          => date("F d, Y H:i:s", time()),
);

$ba = new BannerAd();
?>
```

2nd

```
Fatal error: Class 'FOrum' not found in /home/musthand/public_html/interface/forum.php on line 33

    <?php 
global $es;
global $ui;
global $member_id;
global $base_url;
global $member_url;
global $image_url;
global $admin_url;
require_once("includes/EliteScript.php");
$es = new EliteScript();
$ui = new UserInterface();
$es->RequireMember();
$member_id = $es->GetMemberId();
$base_url = $es->GetConfig("baseUrl");
$member_url = $es->GetConfig("memberUrl");
$image_url = $es->GetConfig("imageUrl");
$es->DisplayHeader("Forum", "member.php");
$_REQUEST["do"];
display_main();
$es->DisplayFooter();


function display_main()
{
    global $es;
    global $ui;
    global $member_id;
    global $base_url;
    global $member_url;
    global $image_url;
    global $admin_url;
    $cur_sign = $es->GetCurrencySign();
    $f = new FOrum();
    echo "<script>\n</script>\n\n<div class=\"bigHeader\">Forum</div>\n";
    echo $ui->GenerateMessageBox("msg", 0, 5);
    echo $ui->GenerateErrorBox("err", 0, 5);
    echo "\n";
    echo $ui->DisplayToolTip("Forum", "Below you can participate in the company forum.");
    echo "<br>\n\n\n";
    $q = "SELECT * FROM forumSections ORDER BY id";
    $r = mysql_query($q);
    while( $l = mysql_fetch_array($r) ) 
    {
        $l_sid = $l["id"];
        $l_sec_name = htmlentitiesi($l["name"]);
        echo "<div class=\"header\">";
        echo $l_sec_name;
        echo "</div>\n<table cellspacing=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\" border=\"0\" width=\"100%\" class=\"dataTbl\">\n<tr class=\"tblHeader\">\n<td>Forum</td>\n<td width=\"50\" align=\"center\">Topics</td>\n<td width=\"50\" align=\"center\">Replies</td>\n<td width=\"150\" align=\"right\">Last Post Info</td>\n</tr>\n";
        $html = NULL;
        $qb = "SELECT * FROM forums WHERE sectionId='" . $l_sid . "' ORDER BY id";
        $rb = mysql_query($qb);
        while( $lb = mysql_fetch_array($rb) ) 
        {
            $l_fid = $lb["id"];
            $l_name = htmlentitiesi($lb["name"]);
            $l_desc = htmlentitiesi($lb["description"]);
            $l_topics = $f->GetForumTopicCount($l_fid);
            $l_replies = $f->GetForumReplyCount($l_fid);
            $html .= "<tr class=\"tblRowA\">\n\t\t\t<td style=\"padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;\">\n\t\t\t<a href=\"\"><b>" . $l_name . "</b></a>\n\t\t\t<div style=\"padding-top: 5px;\">\n\t\t\t" . $l_desc . "\n\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td align=\"center\">" . $l_topics . "</td>\n\t\t\t<td align=\"center\">" . $l_replies . "</td>\n\t\t\t<td align=\"right\">" . $l_lastpost . "</td>\n\t\t\t</tr>";
        }
        echo $html;
        echo "</table>\n\n";
    }
    echo "\n\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n\n\n\n\n\n<div class=\"header\">News & Updates</div>\n<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" border=\"0\" width=\"100%\">\n";
    $html = NULL;
    $q = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY added DESC,id DESC LIMIT 5";
    $r = mysql_query($q);
    while( $l = mysql_fetch_array($r) ) 
    {
        $l_id = $l["id"];
        $l_title = htmlentitiesi($l["title"]);
        $l_date = date("M jS", strtotime($l["added"]));
        $html .= "<tr class=\"sepLine\"><td width=\"20\"><img src=\"" . $image_url . "/note.png\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\"></td><td><a href=\"" . $member_url . "/news.php?do=view&id=" . $l_id . "\">" . $l_title . "</a> <i style=\"color:gray;\">(" . $l_date . ")</i></td></tr>\n";
    }
    if( !$html ) 
    {
        $html = "<tr class=\"sepLine\"><td style=\"color: gray;\">Currently no news and updates...</td></tr>";
    }

    echo $html;
    echo "</table>\n<br>\n\n<div class=\"header\">Account Summary</div>\n\n<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" border=\"0\" width=\"100%\">\n<tr class=\"sepLine\">\n<td width=\"20\"><img src=\"";
    echo $image_url;
    echo "/user.png\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\"></td>\n<td width=\"175\"><b>Member Info:</b></td>\n<td>";
    echo $username;
    echo " (#";
    echo $member_id;
    echo ") <i>(<a href=\"mailto:";
    echo $email;
    echo "\">";
    echo $email;
    echo "</a>)</i></td>\n<td align=\"right\"><a href=\"";
    echo $member_url;
    echo "/preferences.php\">[Preferences]</a></td>\n</tr>\n</table>\n\n<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" border=\"0\" width=\"100%\">\n<tr><td class=\"toolTip\">\nYou must ";
    echo $req_text;
    echo " before participating.</td></tr>\n</table>\n\n\n\n\n<div class=\"header\">Current Active ";
    echo $token_label;
    echo "s</div>\n\n<table cellspacing=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\" border=\"0\" width=\"100%\" class=\"dataTbl\">\n<tr class=\"tblHeader\">\n<td width=\"50\">ID</td>\n<td>Type</td>\n<td width=\"40\">Units</td>\n<td width=\"80\">Amount</td>\n<td width=\"150\">Earned So Far</td>\n<td width=\"80\">Created</td>\n</tr>\n\n";
    $tok_types = $es->GetConfig("tokenTypes");
    $html = NULL;
    $tblClass = "tblRowA";
    $q = "SELECT * FROM tokens WHERE memberId='" . $member_id . "' AND status = 'ACTIVE' ORDER BY created DESC,id DESC";
    $r = mysql_query($q);
    while( $l = mysql_fetch_array($r) ) 
    {
        $l_id = $l["id"];
        $l_type = $l["type"];
        $tok_arr = $tok_types[$l_type];
        $l_name = htmlentitiesi($tok_arr["name"]);
        $l_amt = $l["amount"];
        $l_esf = $l["earnedSoFar"];
        $l_exp_type = $l["expireType"];
        $l_exp_val = $l["expiresOnValue"];
        $l_created = $l["createdDate"];
        $l_lastroi = $l["lastRoiDate"];
        $l_incycle = $l["inCycle"];
        $l_status = $l["status"];
        if( $l_status == "ACTIVE" ) 
        {
            $lb_status = "<span style=\"color: darkgreen;\">Active</span>";
        }
        else
        {
            if( $l_status == "EXPIRED" ) 
            {
                $lb_status = "<span style=\"color: red;\">Expired</span> as of " . date("M jS, y", strtotime($l["expiresDate"]));
            }

        }

        if( $l_created == $l_lastroi && $l_incycle <= 1 ) 
        {
            $l_lastearn_text = "Never";
        }
        else
        {
            $l_lastearn_text = date("M jS, y", strtotime($l_lastroi));
        }

        $l_units = sprintf("%d", $l["units"]);
        $l_earned_per = sprintf("%.2f", $l_esf / $l_amt * 100);
        $earned_per_style = "color: gray;";
        if( 100 < $l_earned_per ) 
        {
            $earned_per_style = "color: darkgreen;";
        }

        $l_created_date = date("M jS, y", $l["created"]);
        if( $l_exp_type == "value" ) 
        {
            $l_exp_text = sprintf("%.2f", $l_exp_val) . "%";
            $l_exp_text .= " <i>(" . $cur_sign . sprintf("%.2f", $l_amt * $l_exp_val / 100) . ")</i>";
        }
        else
        {
            if( $l_exp_type == "date" ) 
            {
                $l_exp_text = date("M jS, y", $l["expires"]);
            }
            else
            {
                if( $l_exp_type == "never" ) 
                {
                    $l_exp_text = "No Set Expiry";
                }

            }

        }

        $lb_amt = number_format($l_amt, 2);
        $lb_esf = number_format($l_esf, 2);
        $html .= "\n\t\t<tr class=\"" . $tblClass . "\">\n\t\t<td>#" . $l_id . "</td>\n\t\t<td><b>" . $l_name . "</b></td>\n\t\t\n\t\t<td>" . $l_units . "</td>\n\t\t<td>" . $cur_sign . $lb_amt . "</td>\n\t\t<td>" . $cur_sign . $lb_esf . " <i style=\"" . $earned_per_style . "\">(" . $l_earned_per . "%)</i></td>\n\t\t<td>" . $l_created_date . "</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr class=\"" . $tblClass . "\">\n\t\t<td colspan=\"6\" style=\"padding-left: 20px;\">\n\t\t\n\t\t<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" border=\"0\">\n\t\t<tr><td width=\"170\">\n\t\t<u>Last Earn Date:</u> " . $l_lastearn_text . "\n\t\t</td><td width=\"190\">\n\t\t<u>Expires:</u> " . $l_exp_text . "\n\t\t</td><td>\n\t\t<u>Status:</u> " . $lb_status . "\n\t\t</td></tr>\n\t\t</table>\n\t\t\n\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>";
        $tblClass = $tblClass == "tblRowA" ? "tblRowB" : "tblRowA";
    }
    if( !$html ) 
    {
        $html .= "<tr class=\"" . $tblClass . "\"><td colspan=\"7\"><span style=\"color: gray;\">Currently no active " . $token_label . "s...</span></td></tr>";
    }

    echo $html;
    echo "</table>\n\n<br><br>\n\n";
}


?>
```

They used to work fine on old server, I don't know what's up with these errors on new one.

They're defined somewhere in somefile, there are 800+ files and it's hard to search in each and every.

Is there any way that we can make the server look of the actual file where these classes or variables were defined?

Comment: These comments are separate issues. 
The first one could be to do with PHP version, the way it is handling exceptions, or the error could have been there all along and you just had error reporting suppressed on your old server.
The second error indicates the class is missing. It could be under a different namespace, in a different location, or there could be an error with your autoloader

Comment: How do I fix it then?

Comment: The first issue was fixed with "shaddy's" reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was never working well. It is bad written. The reason you did not see errors, in your old server is that you had lower error reporting or the whole error reporting was turned off. When you are developing something you should always develop with turned on error reporting, so you can see your mistakes.

The first problem is here

```
if(!is_object($es)) {
```

You check directly if `$es` is object, but this is wrong, because this statement is at the top of the file, and `$es` will be aways undefined unless you import it from the global scope, like this:

```
global $es;

if(!is_object($es)) {
```

Your second error is because you have referenced wrongly the `Forum` class:

```
$f = new FOrum();
```

I suppose it should be:

```
$f = new Forum();
```

Comment: My developer developed the script bro. global $es; fixed the first issue. but the 2nd didn't after changing it to $f = new Forum();

Comment: @Steve You should search then what is the correct name of the forum class, it is because class with such name does not exists. I can not guess it remotely sorry.

Comment: It's ok bro, Thank you for your first fix.